# Unable to start VMWare Workstation after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, kernel, vmware-workstation

After upgrading to 13.04 I am unable to start VMWorkstation. I get the following message:

> Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded
>   into the running kernel.
>
> Kernel Headers 3.8.0-19-generic
>
> Kernel headers for version 3.8.0-19-generic were not found. If you
>   have installed them in a non-default path you can specify the path
>   below.

Does anyone have any idea what to do next?

Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

If I direct the path to:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic
```

I get the following message:

> C header files matching your running kernel were not found.

Thanks

***Additional:***

As suggested I run this in terminal:

```
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux 

sudo ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h 

sudo ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h 

sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

However, now I get the following:

> Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the kernel 
>   CANCEL / INSTALL

I INSTALL, the window closes and nothing happens.... Any ideas?

***ADDITIONAL:***

I installed this:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolbox open-vm-tools-dev
```

And it all launched...

Many thanks for the suggestions and help... This is what I love about Ubuntu... it has a great helpful community... !

Note: Also found this which may help others too: [HERE](http://mergy.org/2013/03/three-tips-to-get-vmware-workstation-9-going-on-kernel-3-8-0/)

***ADDITIONAL ERROR:***

Could not open /dev/vmmon: Is a directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.

Failed to initialize monitor device.

Monitor settings all greyed out

***RESOLUTION:***

Re-installation of Nvidia Drivers

Comment: I also had to use the patch here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2107900&p=12522784#post12522784

With the changes mentioned here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2107900&p=12544708#post12544708

Comment: Could you add instead an answer with the content of "RESOLUTION" section?

Comment: Solved for Ubuntu 19: http://rglinuxtech.com/?p=2522#comment-55900 https://gist.github.com/PiN73/7a890b21f2d2dd22bdc0219b0eebc00e

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hit same problem here with Ubuntu 13.04 last month.  At the time, upgrading to VMWare player 5.0.2 build-1031769 solved the problem.  Fast forward a month, hit a new problem today after recent 13.04 updates, again VMWare would not start.  Latest VM player version is still 5.0.2.  Google lead me to this explanation:

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/446490?start=0&tstart=0

Running the following vmware command with root privs solved the problem for me:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

HTH

Comment: this did the trick.

Comment: If You still have issues try to download and install vmware again: http://itsfoss.com/install-vmware-player-ubuntu-1310/

Comment: This solved the problem for me on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) open-vm-dkms
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

then

```
sudo vmware-config-tools.pl
```

... and you are done.

Comment: This got it running again.  Combine that with the patch to fix the vmnnet component.  Then I ran sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all.

Answer (score 3):

I installed the suggested packages as above, but it still gave me the same error.  Installing the latest VMWare Player solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I already had the latest VMWare Player installed with the exact same problem. Simply reinstalling did help, i.e. uninstalling first and then installing again:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
sudo bash ~/Downloads/VMware-Player-5.0.2-1031769.x86_64.txt
```

Comment: This worked for me. I chose to keep my config files when uninstalling, so after reinstall everything is as before (e.g. all my VMs are still there), and the whole thing only took 3 minute.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the solutions above including a fresh install and it still would not start. It still said, "Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the kernel CANCEL / INSTALL"

After much research, what I had to do is this:
I opened a terminal and then entered:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolbox open-vm-tools-dev
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

and then:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all --appname="VMware Player" --icon="vmware-player"
```

It started right up after that. I hope this helps.

Comment: why you are installing " open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolbox open-vm-tools-dev " on a host machine on which vmware workstation is going to installed ? they are meant to be install in Virtual machine ( guest os of vmware )

Comment: yes , I think the same way, they are for virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Ubuntu VMWare Player install page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player), use

`sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

to install the headers.  Then, you can either let it install or you can uninstall and reinstall vmware player.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the main issue with vmware workstation on 13.04 is compiling modules like vmci.ko.  The easiest way to get these is  to do `apt-get install open-vm-dkms`.  This installs vmci.ko, and friends.

Answer (score 1):

YMMV, but if you have trouble with vmci-related errors (in Linux Kernel 3.8.*), [this bash script posted by vincent](https://askubuntu.com/a/294691/167903) *may* work.
Use it after uninstalling the VMWare product first and then installing again:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $UID != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Please run this script with sudo:"
    echo "sudo $0 $*"
    exit 1
fi

sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h

cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
sudo tar -xf vmci.tar
cd vmci-only/linux
sudo sed '127s/.*/   .remove = vmci_remove_device,/' driver.c > driver.c.tmp
mv driver.c.tmp driver.c
sudo sed '1753s/.*/static int/' driver.c > driver.c.tmp
mv driver.c.tmp driver.c
sudo sed '1981s/.*/static void/' driver.c > driver.c.tmp
mv driver.c.tmp driver.c
cd ../..
sudo tar -cf vmci.tar vmci-only/
sudo rm vmci-only/ -Rf
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
sudo rm /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
echo "Done"
```

Also keep an eye for [VMware article in Arch Linux's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware). This article is mainly for Arch Linux but most of patches/tricks/workarounds can be applied for Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall VMWare workstation using the command

```
sudo vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-workstation
```

then install the following dependencies ***dpkg-dev, g++, gcc, lib6-dev, libc-dev, make*** using the command below

```
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
sudo apt update
sudo reboot
```

Finally, reinstall VMWare workstation.