# VMware 9 install not opening after extraction on 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, vmware

A bit of a linux noob here, I'm trying to get VMware installed and I've finally gotten to the point where I can leave terminal and do the easy work lol, but now I'm stuck again.

I followed [these](http://vmwaremine.com/2012/09/27/vmware-workstation-9-installation-on-ubuntu/) instructions and when I get to this part where it extracts the folder the installer doesn't open.

[image: Extracting VMware installer]

I tried running `vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` in the terminal but the last line says something like "could not install all modules check log for details"

The last lines of the log file say:

```
x’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function] 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors 
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-exlEke/vmci-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1 
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... 
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-exlEke/vmci-only] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic' 
make: *** [vmci.ko] Error 2 
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-exlEke/vmci-only' 
Unable to install all modules. See log for details.
```

A user in chat [said it looked like a problem with the kernel modules](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9330898#9330898). How can I get VMware Workstation 9 to install under Ubuntu 13.04, kernel `3.8.0-19-generic`?

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu 64bit installed?

Comment: Yeah 64bit 13.04

Comment: open terminal and type  > vmware  < update your question with the output and have you install > sudo apt-get install build-essential  ?????

Comment: ![VMware output](http://i41.tinypic.com/2jaars4.png).

Comment: That's the output i got. Sorry tried to make the image appear without the link, but not sure if that works in the comments section. And i did not have build-essential installed, but did install it and tried to do the install again and got the same result as before.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to see where this is going. I'm guessing that I'm in the same boat as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286326/unable-to-start-vmware-workstation-after-upgrade-to-13-04?rq=1) guy. Am I right? And if so, which steps from that thread would I need to do now? I see that he was told to try the one step after he had tried to browse for the path of the headers to install, but then he hit install and said the window closed but nothing happened. Do I need to enter those codes? Or can I skip that part and just install the vmware tools line at the end where he got it to work?

Comment: So i did everything that guy did in the link i referred to in my previous comment and I'm still not getting the installer to come up. Same thing happens as shown in the screen shot.

Comment: Any ideas? Still can't figure it out.

Comment: [We're currently trying to work through this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8681/vmware-9-install-not-opening-after-extraction-on-13-04)

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for me:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2107900

launch this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $UID != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Please run this script with sudo:"
    echo "sudo $0 $*"
    exit 1
fi

sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h

cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
sudo tar -xf vmci.tar
cd vmci-only/linux
sudo sed '127s/.*/   .remove = vmci_remove_device,/' driver.c > driver.c.tmp
mv driver.c.tmp driver.c
sudo sed '1753s/.*/static int/' driver.c > driver.c.tmp
mv driver.c.tmp driver.c
sudo sed '1981s/.*/static void/' driver.c > driver.c.tmp
mv driver.c.tmp driver.c
cd ../..
sudo tar -cf vmci.tar vmci-only/
sudo rm vmci-only/ -Rf
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
sudo rm /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade to 13.04 Vmware stopped working. I removed Vmware Workstation, installed again and run this script upper. Old config is working, old vm's are running :D