# VMware Workstation: Error, modules must be compiled... - how to fix?

Tags: kernel, 13.04, vmware

when I try to launch VMWARE-WORKSTATION, I get the following error:

> Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded
>   into the kernel CANCEL / INSTALL

No errors, when I select INSTALL nothing happens just closes.

I install manually:

> sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms
>   open-vm-toolbox open-vm-tools-dev

But already installed to the latest versions.

I will start a bounty to fix this.

Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ uname -a
Linux pst007x-Serval-Professional 3.9.0-030900-generic #201304291257 SMP Mon Apr 29 16:58:15 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled all components, but same problem.

I have tried a different Kernel, but end up with the same problem.

Tried this as suggested: [here](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2038648)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd
cp -prn /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source-backup
mkdir fixed
cd fixed
find /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source -name "*.tar" -exec tar xf '{}' \;

## add missing header on kernels
sed -i '/#include "compat_wait.h"/a\#include "compat_sched.h"' vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c
sed -i '/#include "compat_page.h"/a\#include "compat_sched.h"' vmci-only/include/pgtbl.h
## comment out an invalid definition
sed -i 's|\(extern void poll_initwait(compat_poll_wqueues \*);\)|//\1|' *-only/include/compat_wait.h

tar cf vmblock.tar vmblock-only
tar cf vmci.tar vmci-only
tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
tar cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
tar cf vmppuser.tar vmppuser-only
tar cf vsock.tar vsock-only

cp -p *.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include/linux
ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h
ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h
cd

vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

# clean up
cd
rm -rf fixed
cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include/linux
rm autoconf.h utsrelease.h
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/
rm -rf source-backup
cd
```

Didn't work, results of script in terminal:

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~/Desktop$ sudo ./run
[sudo] password for pst007x: 
sed: can't read vmci-only/include/pgtbl.h: No such file or directory
sed: can't read *-only/include/compat_wait.h: No such file or directory
tar: vmppuser-only: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./autoconf.h’: File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./utsrelease.h’: File exists
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmmon-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/filter.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmnet-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/block.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/control.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/file.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/filesystem.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/inode.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/module.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/stubs.o
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c:38:4: warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c:38:4: warning: (near initialisation for ‘LinkDentryOps.d_revalidate’) [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c: In function ‘DentryOpRevalidate’:
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c:104:7: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘actualDentry->d_op->d_revalidate’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c:104:7: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct nameidata *’
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/super.o
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/control.c: In function ‘ExecuteBlockOp’:
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/control.c:285:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/control.c:296:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘putname’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from include/linux/proc_fs.h:5:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/control.c:28:
include/linux/fs.h:2040:13: note: expected ‘struct filename *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/inode.c:49:4: warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/linux/inode.c:49:4: warning: (near initialisation for ‘RootInodeOps.lookup’) [enabled by default]
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/vmblock.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "putname" [/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/vmblock.ko] undefined!
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/vmblock.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only/vmblock.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only'
cp -f vmblock.ko ./../vmblock.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmblock-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/vmciKernelIf.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/common/vmciContext.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/common/vmciDoorbell.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/common/vmciDriver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/common/vmciDatagram.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/common/vmciEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/common/vmciHashtable.o
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:127:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:127:4: error: initialiser element is not constant
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:127:4: error: (near initialisation for ‘vmci_driver.remove’)
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:1754:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘vmci_probe_device’
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:1982:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘vmci_remove_device’
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:119:12: warning: ‘vmci_probe_device’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:121:13: warning: ‘vmci_remove_device’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:2063:1: warning: ‘vmci_interrupt’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:2137:1: warning: ‘vmci_interrupt_bm’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:1717:1: warning: ‘vmci_enable_msix’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
make: *** [vmci.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-tGleah/vmci-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.

pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~/Desktop$
```

Tried as suggested below, but same issue:

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
[sudo] password for pst007x: 
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmmon-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/filter.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmnet-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/block.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/control.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/file.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/filesystem.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/inode.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/module.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/stubs.o
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/control.c: In function ‘ExecuteBlockOp’:
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/control.c:285:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/control.c:296:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘putname’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from include/linux/proc_fs.h:5:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/control.c:28:
include/linux/fs.h:2040:13: note: expected ‘struct filename *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c:38:4: warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c:38:4: warning: (near initialisation for ‘LinkDentryOps.d_revalidate’) [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c: In function ‘DentryOpRevalidate’:
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c:104:7: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘actualDentry->d_op->d_revalidate’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.c:104:7: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct nameidata *’
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/inode.c:49:4: warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/inode.c:49:4: warning: (near initialisation for ‘RootInodeOps.lookup’) [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/linux/super.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/vmblock.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "putname" [/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/vmblock.ko] undefined!
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/vmblock.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only/vmblock.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only'
cp -f vmblock.ko ./../vmblock.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmblock-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/vmciKernelIf.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/common/vmciContext.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/common/vmciDatagram.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/common/vmciDoorbell.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/common/vmciDriver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/common/vmciHashtable.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/common/vmciEvent.o
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:127:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:127:4: error: initialiser element is not constant
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:127:4: error: (near initialisation for ‘vmci_driver.remove’)
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:1754:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘vmci_probe_device’
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:1982:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘vmci_remove_device’
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:119:12: warning: ‘vmci_probe_device’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:121:13: warning: ‘vmci_remove_device’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:2063:1: warning: ‘vmci_interrupt’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:2137:1: warning: ‘vmci_interrupt_bm’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:1717:1: warning: ‘vmci_enable_msix’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic'
make: *** [vmci.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-IFjtiM/vmci-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.

pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$
```

**Moderator:
I have tried all suggestions in other posts, but they do not address this particular issue.**

**This is not a duplicate, the other postings do not address this specific issue and offer no solutions**

Comment: try this > sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: After google-fu: "vmware" "driver.c" "__devexit_p" error. 

As stated [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160031), you need to apply a patch, the problem is: [that patch](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/432897) is not for your specific kernel. But... give it a try anyway...

You should try to google-fu like that, but add your kernel version. I found nothing to your kernel version, so you may need to ask for a patch to that kernel in the vmware forums.

Comment: I have the patch, I had it installed when running a previous Kernel, worked well, then.. but does not install on my current system... Perhaps vmware cannot run on the Kernel I am using...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I has same problem. After some joojling(googling), i resolved my problem ny following steps:

1. (I am not sure that this does any affect about my problem) [as @pst007x executed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286326/unable-to-start-vmware-workstation-after-upgrade-to-13-04)

   ```
   cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux 
   sudo ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h 
   sudo ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h 
   sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
   ```
2. I ran following code as @Qasim suggested

   ```
   sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
   ```

I have Ubuntu 13.04-64bit, powered by kernel 3.8.0-21-generic and VMware Player 5.0.2 build-1031769

Good luck!

Comment: i think kernel  3.8.0-21-generic fixed the vmware issue ....

Comment: It did not.  Had to add in the version.h link and run the vmware-modconfig command from above, then the install worked.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you have the wrong kernel headers, it looks like one of those suggestions is trying to use kernel headers for 3.9.0, doesn't 13.04 use kernel version 3.88 ?  Try getting the kernel headers from apt, do:

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` (borrowed from [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-kernel-headers-package/))

and then try to install it again

Comment: I had the issue with the Kernel shipped with 13.04 (worked fine on the older kernel shipped with 12.10). I had to upgrade my Kernel to 3.9.0 because after upgrading to 13.04 my system would intermittently hang on boot, upgrading the kernel resolved this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04. When I started VMware I would get the same message:

```
Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the kernel CANCEL / INSTALL
```

When I would click INSTALL then nothing would happen. I checked /var/log/ and apport was reporting the following error:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 3061) Thu Apr 25 08:48:51 2013: executable: /usr/lib/vmware/bin/appLoader (command line "/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-gksu --sudo-mode --message=Please\ enter\ your\ password\ to\ proceed. '/usr/bin/vmware-modconfig'\ --icon='vmware-workstation'\ --appname='VMware'")
```

There appears to be an issue with /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-gksu that causes it to crash. I can reliably reproduce the problem everytime I run the command. I was able to solve the problem by running the command manually. Here are the commands I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic
sudo /usr/bin/vmware-modconfig --icon=vmware-workstation --appname=VMware
```

Do you see something similar in /var/log/apport?

Comment: After doing some additional research, I believe the problem is related to 13.04 removing support for gksu. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default-in-13-04

Comment: I am still able to run gksu command to launch Nautilus for example...

Comment: Tried: sudo /usr/bin/vmware-modconfig --icon=vmware-workstation --appname=VMware ....... but VMware launches, and display a COMPILING message, but hangs...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, combining some solutions above worked for me, I'm a developer so I already had the most recent linux headers, but just in case you don't

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

A couple of errors were thrown, despite them it's now working perfectly.

It should be noted that this method was tested with VMWare Player, not workstation (my workstation key is out of date, the latest I have is version 7)

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which worked for me [here](https://gist.github.com/PiN73/7a890b21f2d2dd22bdc0219b0eebc00e):

> ```
> git clone -b workstation-15.0.2 https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
> cd vmware-host-modules
> tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
> tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
> sudo cp -v vmmon.tar vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
> sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
> ```

You can replace the Workstation version with the current version in the git repository name above.