# VMware Workstation 10 at startup vmmon error

Tags: vmware-workstation

Until yesterday I was having Workstation 9 startup with ubuntu (just added an entry in the Startup Applications GUI). When I start my ubuntu, workstation comes up and every thing runs fine.

Then, I upgraded to Workstation 10. Every thing appears to work with no isues, EXCEPT, it will not startup my virtual machine when it is launched at startup. It shows these errors:

```
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
```

then,

```
Failed to initialize monitor device.
```

then,

```
Unable to change virtual machine power state: Internal error
```

Otherwise, if I just try to play the virtual machine again (by pressing play), it works.

Maybe it is a VMware bug.

Please, any advise?

Comment: Does /dev/vmmon exist? `ls -al /dev/vmmon`

Comment: yes: me@me-Satellite-L655:~$ ls -al /dev/vmmon
crw------- 1 root root 10, 165 Sep  8 01:58 /dev/vmmon

Comment: Post from user [Matg](http://askubuntu.com/users/192553/matg): See this question: [Unable to start VMWare Workstation after upgrade to 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286326/unable-to-start-vmware-workstation-after-upgrade-to-13-04). There's a command `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all`. Does this help?

Comment: No. I tried that before posting.

Comment: Sounds like the root of the problem is that the vmware monitoring service may have installed/built but isn't starting properly.  No ideas on why.  The answer below just patchwork fixes by installing it again.  I would suspect that doesn't persist through a reboot, or you didn't rebuild the modules after a kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

Run this from the command line:

```
 sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Then start the vmplayer.

Comment: Actually, the problem got fixed by itself. Sorry for not posting.

Comment: This command not work for me, the out was:

    Starting VMware services:
    Virtual machine monitor                                            failed
    Virtual ethernet                                                   failed

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be solved with this command: `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all`

Answer (score 0):

I got "failed to get gcc information" when I tried the above command.

I started the vmware-workstation-server in init.d and my VMs now start. I didn't need to run the above command again.

```
cd /etc/init.d/
./vmware-workstation-server start
```

Comment: You have a typo in your command

Comment: Also what do you mean by `above command`? This looks rather like a comment to another answer.. at least please provide a link to the post you are referring to.